hist() breaks are either uneven or exclude one bar?
Almost certainly a head-smakingly simple solution ...
I want to use a set of histograms as the diagonal in a pairs() chart in which different rating-scale items are correlated. (Typically these are integer variables ranging from '1' to '5' but sometimes '1' to '7', '-3' to '3', etc., or as a summated scale ranging from '5' to '25'.)
So I want the histogram to show a bar for each level in the scale: 5 bars for a 1-5 scale, 7 bars for a 1-7 scale, etc.
But the hist() function instead gives me 8 bars for a 1-5 scale, 6 bars for a 1-7 scale, 8 bars for a 1-9 scale, etc.
n <- 128
set.seed(42)
x1 <- sample(c(1:5), size = n, replace = TRUE) 
x2 <- sample(c(1:7), size = n, replace = TRUE) 
x3 <- sample(c(1:9), size = n, replace = TRUE)

hist(x1, breaks = "Sturges", right = TRUE)


hist(x2, breaks = "Sturges", right = TRUE)


hist(x3, breaks = "Sturges", right = TRUE)


Created on 2024-08-03 with reprex v2.1.1
If I use the breaks = "FD" or breaks = "Scott" options then I always get 1 fewer bars than number of values.
Changing the right = TRUE and right = FALSE options simply changes which bar is left out.
I expect that the issue has something to do the the "pretty" process within hist(), but I can't work out how to work around it.
Any thoughts?

You can pass explicit values to the breaks argument of hist() to control how the data are binned. For example, you can get five bins for your x1 values by setting breaks = 0:5.
n <- 128
set.seed(42)
x1 <- sample(c(1:5), size = n, replace = TRUE) 
table(x1)
#> x1
#>  1  2  3  4  5 
#> 29 34 15 24 26
hist(x1, breaks = 0:5)

Created on 2024-08-02 with reprex v2.0.2

In the jargon R uses, histograms are a kind of bar plot for continuous data.  Since you have discrete data, you still want a bar plot, but not a histogram.  The basic form is
n <- 128
set.seed(42)
x1 <- sample(c(1:5), size = n, replace = TRUE) 

barplot(table(x1))


Created on 2024-08-03 with reprex v2.1.0
with lots of options for changing the formatting.
Edited to add:  By the way, sometimes you may have a small dataset with zero counts for some values.  The code above will omit those values.  If you want to show them, the convert your data into a factor, including the missing levels.  For example,
x2 <- x1[1:10]
barplot(table(x2))


x2 <- factor(x2, levels = 1:5)
barplot(table(x2))


Created on 2024-08-03 with reprex v2.1.0
